# Count Spins around Origin of Complex Locus

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Given a smooth and nice function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

For a parameter range $t\in [0,1]$ is there a simple method to count the number of rotations the locus of $f$ performs around the origin? Mathematically that is roughly this measure:

$$R=\int_0^1 \left.\frac{d}{dt}(\angle f(t))\right|_{t=t'} dt'$$

(I integrate the phase change between two infinitesimally adjacent points on the curve.)

After the fundamental theorem of calculus, this is R=$\angle f(b)-\angle f(a)$. However, here the "modulo" part of the angle is problematic, as it cannot represent how many times the function went around the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a closed path $f$, the [contour integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration) of $\frac1z$ along $f$ is $2\pi\mathrm i$ times the winding number.

If $f$ isn't a closed path, you can consider $\frac{f(t)}{|f(t)|}$ instead. This is a path on the unit circle (on which you can ignore the magnitude and are just integrating a phase factor), and the contour integral is proportional to the angle covered, even if you don't complete an integral number of revolutions about the origin.

Comment: Thanks, the piece of $\int 1/z dz$ was missing to me!